# Capture R console output with RPy

Tags: python, r, stdout, rpy2

I am using the `texreg` package from CRAN to get LaTeX summaries for my R statistics. This package provides the option of either printing the output to the console or to a file. I would like to assign it to a python variable **and** make sure that nothing gets printed (I am piping this to a document via pythonTeX, which is a longer story).

I have uploaded a full example with remote data (in case you want to reproduce it) [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/gist.github.com/TheChymera/7508165/raw/fa5495c02d2716fedbe964b5982b245827750614/RPy+console).

It boils down to doing

```
latex = texreg.texreg(mylm)
```

and getting the output in latex and only in latex.

I have tried a number of approaches

```
latex = texreg.texreg(test1, file='/dev/null', single_row=False)

%pylab inline
%load_ext rmagic 

%Rpush test1
%R latex = texreg(test1, single_row=False)
```

in the afore mentioned notebook but they have all failed :(

Answer (score 0):

Modifying a few lines in your code seems to work for me in the IPython notebook

```
texreg.texreg(test1, file='temp1.tex', single_row=False)
latex = open('temp1.tex').read()
print latex
```

Comment: Sadly, while that works in IPython for some reason texreg's "Computing confidence intervals at a confidence level of 0.95. Use argument "method = 'boot'" for bootstrapped CIs." message still gets passed to PythonTex.

Comment: Those are diagnostic messages from the function. I know that `suppressMessages(texreg(...))` should run the function without the messages, but it will only work if the package authors have used `message` and NOT `print` to output the message. I am not sure how to run this in IPython.

Comment: Alternately, just read the file contents and do a simple regex on the python side to output just the table. There are many SO answers on how to skip first few lines while reading a file.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this... eventually... with the following quite hackish solution:

```
import os
import sys
f = open(os.devnull, 'w')
sys.stdout = f
texreg.texreg(lin_model)
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
latex = open('lm-temp.tex').read()
remove('lm-temp.tex')
return latex
```

Please say so if you can think of a better solution.